# How do I get the pk of a ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

I want to allow uploads that will be stored in the following way:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/' + str(category.pk) + '/' + str(user.pk))

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'category')
```

This way, each upload would be sandboxed in its own directory, first by the category ID and then by the user ID. I wouldn't have to worry about duplicated file names and the directory structure would be neat and organized.

However, `ForeignKey` does not have an instance of `pk`, so the above code does not actually work. Is there a way to store the file in a directory based on the category and user? Or, alternatively, is there another strategy commonly used to organize file uploads in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callable function for [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload%5Fto):

```
import os

def upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('uploads', str(instance.category.pk), str(instance.user.pk))

file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to address here.

The quick thing is that the `pk` of the related `Category` is available on the in-memory `Upload` instance as `self.category_id`, and the `pk` of the related `User` is `self.user_id`.

The somewhat more complicated thing is that to use a dynamic `upload_to`, you have to give it a callable rather than an arbitrary expression. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

> This may also be a callable, such as a function, which will be called to obtain the upload path, including the filename. This callable must be able to accept two arguments, and return a Unix-style path (with forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system. The two arguments that will be passed are:
>
> instance
>
> An instance of the model where the FileField is defined. More specifically, this is the particular instance where the current file is being attached.
>
> In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a value for its primary key field.
>
> filename
>
> The filename that was originally given to the file. This may or may not be taken into account when determining the final destination path.

So you'll want to define a function that takes the `Upload` instance and returns the desired path:

```
def upload_location(upload, original_filename):
    return os.path.join(str(upload.category_id), str(upload.user_id), original_filename)
```

Or something like that. Then use it in the model:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location)
```

Comment: I was thinking to use `os.path.join` Don't think I have copied you :)

Comment: @AamirAdnan - heh. Not like that's a deeply held secret. I admit I was reminded of the need to stringify the integer FKs by your answer.